# In IntelliJ, what inspection is "TS6053: File ... not found' and how can I run it on the whole project?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I think this is some kind of TypeScript plugin, but I don't know what it is.

I can't determine what it is based on my installed plugins. How can I run the analysis for whatever plugin this is on the whole project? Currently, I have to open each individual file and wait for it to run the mystery analysis.

Comment: This file in `node_modules/` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a built-in Typescript [language service](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API); it can be turned on/off in **Settings | Languages and Frameworks | TypeScript**.
When using it, all dependent files are not sent to server on re-highlighting the current file - it would be too expensive. That's why highlighting is not updated until you open a file in editor. You can try using **Compile All** in [TypeScript tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/typescript-compiler-tool-window.html) to see all errors.

To have the errors from all files shown while editing, you can toggle **Show project errors** button in TypeScript tool window; but note that this would slow down the performance